# How to Implement PUSH NOTIFICATION in Windows Universal App 10?

Tags: push-notification, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

This may be a duplicate question. But I did not find any solution yet. Can you please provide any example or sample code for registering App for PUSH NOTIFICATION on uwp 10?

Client code needed and Push notification type is Server to client. Client should register for receiving Server PUSH and Handle the push coming from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented push notification. So, It may help someone.
Add a new method in App.xaml.cs:

```
private async Task InitNotificationsAsync()
{            
    // Get a channel URI from WNS.
    var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager
                .CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();            
    channel.PushNotificationReceived += Channel_PushNotificationReceived;            
}
```

Call this method inside `OnLaunched` method:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
     await InitNotificationsAsync();
     ...
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link for localpush: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/10/05/sending-a-local-tile-notification-in-windows-10.aspx

For push notification from server to work, read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

Comment: I need push from server. I have seen second link but i am unable to implement that in my app. Can you please provide or frame that code into class. As i am novice in Windows universal app development.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868221%28v=win.10%29?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396

follow this step by step, get the channel Url, save it to server. Use the channel so send push later.

Comment: anywhere, but you can start with App.xaml.cs

Comment: Did you try Azure Push Notifications? Let me know so I will provide more information.